# How does Timestamp concurrency control handle read-timestamp

Tags: database, concurrency, transactions, timestamp

I'm learning about Time stamp based protocols. I tried to create a live example but I'm not sure if this is correct.

**Each transaction Ti is given timestamp ts(Ti)**

```
If a transaction Ti issues read(X) operation:
     If TS(Ti) < W-timestamp(X)
         Operation rejected.

     If TS(Ti) >= W-timestamp(X)
         Read Operation executed. We set R-timestamp(x) = max(ts(T), R-timestamp(x)


All data-item Timestamps updated.
```

To create a practical example, I made this very simple excel formula (where C1 is TS(Ti) and D1 would be the W-timestamp for x:

```
=IF(C1<D1,"TRUE","FALSE")
```

So I type in:

```
    (C1)           (C2)
   TS(Ti)  |   W-Timestamp  | 
01/02/2015 |  03/02/2015    |   TRUE
```

In first date, the transaction (which is older than stamp) is trying to read a value which has been updated by newer transaction. Since the `Ti<W-timestamp` is `True`, we abort the transaction & restart with a new timestamp.

That does mean the date for `TS(Ti)` now becomes `03/02/2015`? So if we did test again:

```
Execute If: (03/02/2015 >= 03/02/2015) = True
```

We then need to set `R-timestamp(x) = max(ts(T), R-timestamp(x)`

So we end up with:

```
TS          = 03/02/2015
W-timestamp = 03/02/2015
R-timestamp = 03/02/2015 <- is this correct, not sure what to do here.
```

If this practical example correct? What exactly happends to the R-timestamp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's correct.

but it is good to use epoc time for timestamp (in millisecond).

for your example transaction restart to read last updated X from database. Read-timestamp was updated with last timestamp to say a transaction with this timestamp read this data and work based on it. if another transaction needs to change this value (that is, X) must have greater timestamp than Read-Timestamp(X).

Read-Timestamp will be check in write rules.